# Проблемы с сессией php, codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, сессия

Добрый день.

Для корзины покупок использую стандартный класс `codeigniter - cart`. В шапке сайта есть количество товаров в корзине `($this->cart->total_items())`. При добавлении товара в корзину, количество не обновляется. Через некоторое время, если обновить страницу, количество появляется. На `DenWer`'e все работает отлично, загрузил на хостинг, и начались проблемы? При удалении с корзины таже история. Такое чувство что страница кэшируется и при обновлении тянет данные из кэша.

Все просто: Есть форма которая отправляеться методом post

```
public function addToCart()
{
   $logged_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
   if ($logged_in != true)
   {
      redirect('/welcome/login');
   };

   $this->load->model('product_model');
   $Product = $this->product_model->get_product_byid($_POST['productId']);

   $data = array(
           array(
                   'id'      => $_POST['productId'],
                   'qty'     => $_POST['quantity'],
                   'name'     => $_POST['productId'],
                   'price'   => $Product->price));

    $this->cart->insert($data);
    redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

}
```

И в хэдере использую:

```
echo $this->cart->total_items()
```

Comment: пробовали добавлять `salt` ?

Comment: Вы добавляете/удаляете товары в корзину не через AJAX, случаем?

Comment: Нет. AJAX не использую. Salt используеться

Comment: На хостинге PHP 5.5. Хоcтинг smarterasp.

Comment: Спросите в службе поддержки вашего хостера.

Comment: покажите код ajax как вы реагируете на результат. и controller/функцию обработчика этой ajax запроса. возможно не там ошибка

Comment: У меня нет ajax запроса. Пробовал через echo выводить все параметры которые передаются через post - все ок.